# Rails :confirm | How to select “Cancel” by default in confirm box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The confirm-box message appears like it should when the link is clicked.

```
<%= link_to 'Close Account',
    @profile,
    :confirm => "Are you sure?",
    :method => :delete
%>
```

When the confirm-box appears, the "OK" button is selected by default; I want the "Cancel" button selected by default, so that if the user accidentally presses enter then the profile record will be safe and will not be deleted.

Is it possible to have the "Cancel" button selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confirm box is generated by Javascript, using an attribute selector in Rails (note `data-confirm`) on the element. Unfortunately, this box is generated by the browser, so there's no real direct control over it. If you're using the latest version of Rails, I suggest looking into jQuery UI, and using the [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) library. Here, you can make custom confirmations, and maybe even an attribute binding such as `data-uiconfirm`. Which would look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Close Account',
    @profile,
    :data =>
      {:uiconfirm => "Are you sure?"},
    :method => :delete
%>
```

And the attribute binding like so:

```
$('[data-uiconfirm]').dialog(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a browser implemented thing, and there's no way to change the selected box. If you want to get around this, you would have to make your own popup code where you could change the selection.